# UpdatePanel и троллинг скроллингом

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Во время того, как пользователь работает на web-странице, посылается, с определённой частотой, Ajax-запрос к серверу для обновления.

Проблема заключается в том, что вот какая ситуация: пользователь находится на какой-то позиции страницы, прокрутив скролл-бар, например, на положение равное X; в этот момент, посылается Ajax-запрос, используя UpdatePanel; тут пользователь решил прокрутить скролл ещё дальше, например, на положение Y; так вот, когда приходит ответ от сервера на запрос посланный ранее, скролл возращается автоматически в положение X.

Получается своеобразный "троллинг скроллингом". Как можно этот скроллинг (возвращение на положение X) отменить?

P.S. Подозреваю, что нужно как-то использовать `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` в JS, но не знаю, что именно нужно сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О! Всё нашёл, надо было просто на английском искать.

```
        Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false;
```

P.S. Уже в какой раз убеждаюсь в том, что чаще ответы можно найти введя в гугле запрос на английском. Жаль, что у нас пока нет достаточно хороших интернет-ресурсов, способных предоставить подобную помощь. Будем надеется, что Хэшкод в скором времени будет способен:)